# Software Center doesn't work after installing Python 3.4.3

Tags: software-center, python3

I have a problem with my Ubuntu 15.04, after installing Python 3.4.3 I couldn't run the Software Center and this message appears:

```
File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 140
     print time.time()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: When you installed 3.4.3 did you manually change the python symlink or change the setting in alternatives? If so, the answers at the linked question above should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the case, because as of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3

> /usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python2 will point to Python 2.7 and
>   /usr/bin/python3 will point to the latest supported Python 3 version.

```
$ grep -nH python /usr/bin/software-center
/usr/bin/software-center:1:#! /usr/bin/python

$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

Plese check your output of `/usr/bin/python --version`

Comment: the result : Python 3.4.3 

i think there is something going wrong , because always i got this error message 
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f